# I cannot pull objects from database anymore

Tags: python, django, database, python-3.x, sqlite

i am new to python & django. i tried to make a blog (bootstrap template) and the first 4 pages are working with the database and models that i've created. but for the 5th page i somehow cannot pull any data from the objects that i've made in de admin page of django.

i deleted the migrations and redo them several times. even flushed the database and cache. it seems like my models are capable just to 4 classes and not more

this is my **overmij.html** where i tried to pull data (in this case some content from the admin) like the previous pages and it doesn't work.

overmij.html (doesn't show any content)

```
<h1>overmij</h1>



{{info.content}}
```

exercise.html

```
    <!-- Main Content -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
                <div class="post-preview">
                    {% for exercise in exercises %}
                    <a href="{% url 'web_app:exercise_detail' exercise.id %}">
                        <h2 class="post-title">
                            {{exercise.title}}
                        </h2>
                    </a>
                    <p class="post-meta">Posted by
                       XXX
                        {{exercise.published}}</p>
                    <hr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>


                <hr>
                <!-- Pager -->
                <div class="clearfix">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary float-left" href="{% url 'web_app:index' %}">&larr; Go to Articles </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

ex_details.html
`

```
                <h2 class="post-title">
                    {{exercise.title}}
                </h2>

                <p class="post-meta">Posted by
                   XXX
                    {{exercise.published}}</p>
                <hr>
                {{exercise.content}}
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <img src="{{ exercise.image.url }}" height="300">
   </div>
```

`

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Article, Exercise
from .models import Overmij


def index(request):
     return render(request, 'web_app/index.html',{"articles":Article.objects.all})
    
def detail(request, article_id):
        article_detail = get_object_or_404(Article, pk=article_id)
        return render(request, 'web_app/article.html', {'article':article_detail})
    
def exercise(request):
    return render(request, 'web_app/exercise.html', {"exercises":Exercise.objects.all})
      
def ex_details(request, exercise_id):
        exercise_detail = get_object_or_404(Exercise, pk=exercise_id)
        return render(request, 'web_app/ex_details.html', {'exercise':exercise_detail})
    
def overmij(request):
     return render(request, 'web_app/overmij.html',{'info':Overmij.objects.all})  
    
def web_app_list(request):
     return render(request=request, 
            template_name="web_app/web_app_list.html",
            context={"web_app":Article.objects.all})
```

my urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
    
app_name = 'web_app'
urlpatterns = [
    path('list',views.web_app_list, name='list'),
    path('index',views.index, name='index'),
    path('article/<int:article_id>',views.detail, name='detail'),
    path('exercise',views.exercise, name='exercise'),
    path('exercise_details/<int:exercise_id>',views.ex_details, name='exercise_detail'),
    path('overmij',views.overmij, name='overmij'),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime
# Create your models here.


class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = models.TextField()
    published = models.DateTimeField("date published", default= datetime.now())
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', default="")
    
class Exercise(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = models.TextField()
    published = models.DateTimeField("date published", default= datetime.now())
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', default="")
    
class Overmij(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = models.TextField()
    published = models.DateTimeField("date published", default= datetime.now())
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', default="")
    
def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Article, Exercise, Overmij
from django.db import models
# Register your models here.
 
class Web_appAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # field are the names of the colums in the models.py
   # fields = ["title","published","content"]
              
                # to split it
            
            fieldsets = [
                ("Title/date", {"fields":["title","published"]}),
                ("Content", {"fields":["content", "image"]})
            ]
admin.site.register(Article, Web_appAdmin),
admin.site.register(Exercise, Web_appAdmin),
admin.site.register(Overmij, Web_appAdmin),
```

settings.py

````
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'web_app',
 ]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'sampleapp.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['/Users/AdamDawdi/djangoApps/sampleapp/web_app/templates/web_app'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'sampleapp.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "web_app/static"),
     
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_cdn")

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR
```
````

Comment: the # are in dutch now(i am dutch) maybe for others change them

Comment: `{'info':Overmij.objects.all}` You're _referring_ to the all method, but not _calling_ it.    Put parentheses after `all`: `{'info':Overmij.objects.all()}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like with the `exercise` view, your `overmij` view returns a queryset of *all* elements in the db. But in your exercise template, you iterate over the queryset to display the elements of each exercise; you don't do that with the overmij template. If you want to display the content field from each Overmij object, you need to iterate in the template.

```
{% for overmij in info %}
  {{overmij.content}}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I've put another snippet of my other (working) code "ex_details.html" that is almost the same..

Comment: How is that relevant? In that view you pass an ID in the URL and use it to query a specific instance of Exercise. You do that in `detail` for Articles as well, but you *don't* do that in your overmij view.